# Calc many value with many arithmetic operators c++

Tags: c++, math, operators, calc

1. > ```
   > #ifndef CALC_H
   > #define CALC_H
   >
   >
   > class calc
   > {
   >     double numb1;
   >     double numb2;
   >     public:
   >         calc();
   >         void FUN_SUM();
   >         void FUN_Subtraction();
   >         void FUN_Multiplication();
   >         void FUN_Division();
   >         void FUN_Power();
   >         void FUN_Squareroot();
   >         void FUN_Switch();
   >         void FUN_Loob();
   >
   > };
   >
   > #endif // CALC_H
   >
   >
   >
   > #include "calc.h"
   > #include <iostream>
   > #include <cmath>
   > using namespace std;
   > calc::calc()
   > {
   >     numb1 = 0;
   >     numb2 = 0;
   > }
   > void calc::FUN_SUM()
   > {
   >      cout << "Enter number 1 " << endl;
   >     cin >> numb1;
   >     cout << "Enter number 2 " << endl;
   >     cin >> numb2;
   >     double Result_Of_Sum;
   >     Result_Of_Sum = numb1+numb2;
   >     cout << "The result of Sum = " << Result_Of_Sum << endl;
   >
   >
   > }
   >
   > void calc::FUN_Subtraction()
   > {
   >      cout << "Enter number 1 " << endl;
   >  cin >> numb1;
   >  cout << "Enter number 2 " << endl;
   >  cin >> numb2;
   >  double Result_Of_Subtraction;
   >  Result_Of_Subtraction = numb1 - numb2;
   >  cout << "The result of Subtraction = " << Result_Of_Subtraction << endl;
   > }
   > void calc::FUN_Multiplication()
   > {
   >      cout << "Enter number 1 " << endl;
   >     cin >> numb1;
   >     cout << "Enter number 2 " << endl;
   >     cin >> numb2;
   >     double Result_Of_Multiplication;
   >     Result_Of_Multiplication = numb1*numb2;
   >     cout << "The result of Multiplication = " << Result_Of_Multiplication << endl;
   >
   > }
   >
   > void calc::FUN_Division()
   > {
   >     cout << "Enter number 1 " << endl;
   >     cin >> numb1;
   >     cout << "Enter number 2 " << endl;
   >     cin >> numb2;
   >     double Result_Of_Division ;
   >     Result_Of_Division = numb1/numb2;
   >     cout << "The result of Division = " << Result_Of_Division << endl;
   > }
   >
   > void calc::FUN_Power()
   > {
   >     cout << "Enter number 1 " << endl;
   > cin >> numb1;
   > cout << "Enter number 2 " << endl;
   > cin >> numb2;
   > double Result_Of_Power;
   > Result_Of_Power = pow(numb1,numb2);
   > cout << "The result of Power = " << Result_Of_Power << endl;
   > }
   >
   > void calc::FUN_Squareroot()
   > {
   >     cout << "Enter the tow number you want Square root \n";
   >     cin >> numb1;
   >
   >     double Result_Of_Square_root;
   >     Result_Of_Square_root = sqrt(numb1);
   >     cout << "The result of Square root = " << Result_Of_Square_root << endl;
   > }
   > void calc::FUN_Switch()
   > {
   >  int S;
   >     cout << "Enter the number you operator do you want do it  " << endl;
   >     cout << "1- Addition" << endl;
   >     cout << "2- Subtraction" << endl;
   >     cout << "3- Multiplication" << endl;
   >     cout << "4- Division" << endl;
   >     cout << "5- Power" << endl;
   >      cout << "6- Square Root" << endl;
   >       cout << "7- Exit" << endl;
   >     cin >> S;
   >
   >     switch (S)
   >     {
   >     case 1:
   >
   >         FUN_SUM();
   >         break;
   >
   >     case 2:
   >
   >         FUN_Subtraction();
   >         break;
   >
   >     case 3:
   >
   >         FUN_Multiplication();
   >         break;
   >
   >     case 4:
   >
   >         FUN_Division();
   >         break;
   >
   >     case 5:
   >
   >         FUN_Power();
   >         break;
   >
   >     case 6:
   >
   >         FUN_Squareroot();
   >         break;
   >
   >     default :
   >         break;
   >
   >     }
   > }
   >
   > void calc::FUN_Loob()
   > {
   >      char L;
   >
   >     do
   >     {
   >
   >         FUN_Switch();
   >
   >  cout << "Do you want do another operator ( 'y' or 'n'?) \n";
   >         cin >> L;
   > if (L== 'y' || L=='Y' || L=='n' || L=='N')
   >
   >     continue;
   > else
   >     cout << "you are enter roang later\n";
   >
   >     }
   >
   >     while (L == 'Y' || L == 'y' );
   >
   > }
   >
   >
   > #include <iostream>
   > #include "calc.h"
   > using namespace std;
   >
   > int main()
   > {
   >   cout << "Welcome to my simple Calculator\n";
   > calc simple_calc;
   >
   > simple_calc.FUN_Loob();
   > cout << "\n Tank you for use my App :) :) " << endl;
   >
   > return 0; 
   > }
   > ```

my question is how i can enable user Calc any value with operators like regular Calculator

for example 1+9*8-1+5 i want my program do like that but i don`t know how ?? :( :(

Comment: Format your post please. Take some care.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ calculator" and a lot of examples will show up.  Study them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a calculator is not an easy task, as there is more involved:

1. Operator Precedence
2. Grouping
3. Evaluating of expressions

**Operator Precedence**
Operator precedence is the grouping of operations, such as performing all multiplication and division before addition and subtraction.  A calculator program should handle precedence without parenthesis (grouping).

**Grouping**
A more advanced calculator will allow grouping of expressions, using parenthesis.  The calculator should be able to evaluate the inner most expression and work outward.

**Evaluating of Expressions**
This means allowing more than 1 digit numbers, and whitespace between numbers and symbols.  Also, once the expression is *parsed*, it needs to be evaluated.  The calculator should call the appropriate functions based on the operation (specified by the User).

I suggest you allow the User to enter an expression, and your program read it in as a string.  Your program will then *parse* the string, then evaluate the expression(s).

Search the web and StackOverflow for "c++ calculator" for examples.

Comment: thank you for answer me
but i have question some Expressions must be do it from left to right how can i do it  like this example 3-9+8 must be do it from left to right ??

Comment: If you scan your input string starting at index 0, you will be scanning from left to right.

Comment: another question what about declare tow variable as pointer and create (for loop) to add number by user and another (for loop) for Expressions

Comment: You really need to study the other examples.  Too much to discuss on comments and StackOverflow.  You could create a tree for the evaluation and parsing.